# Error in SQL query: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Date' to data type int

Tags: sql, date, formatting, left-join

I have two tables: MTA and FWCS.
I want to LEFT JOIN the FWCS with the MTA on: MTA.CoB = FWCS.CoB AND MTA.[Expo Date] = FWCS.[Period]. The problem is that MTA.[Expo Date] is a date in integer like this:   [image]. FWCS.[Period] is also in integer, but like this:   [image] which you can read as YYYYMMDD.

Im now trying to get MTA.[Expo Date] to the form YYYYMMDD and then convert this back to an integer so I can LEFT JOIN the two tables. I've come up with this:

```
SELECT CAST(FORMAT(CAST(mta.[Expo Date] AS datetime), 'yyyyMMdd') AS INT) AS 'Date' FROM (SELECT * FROM MTA) AS mta
LEFT JOIN FWCS ON mta.CoB = FWCS.CoB AND 'Date' = FWCS.[Period]
```

When I execute this, I get the error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Date' to data type int. After some online browsing, I think it has to do something with the FORMAT()-function because the FORMAT()-function returns the varchar datatype but I'm not exactly sure

Does anyone know how to make this code work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question and tag the special type of sql you're using.